# Modifying the MuiTheme in Material-ui-next

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I currently use the following code to modify the themes in materialUI v.0

```
import { deepOrange900, deepOrange800, deepOrange700, redA400, grey200, grey400, white } from 'material-ui/styles/colors';

exports.darkOrangeTheme = {
    palette: {
        primary1Color: '#21242d',
        primary2Color: '#A6956D',
        primary3Color: '#c10000',
        accent1Color: deepOrange900, //#BF360C
        accent2Color: deepOrange900, //#BF360C
        accent3Color: deepOrange800, //#D84315
        required: redA400, //#FF1744
        borderColor: grey200, //#eeeeee
        disabledColor: grey400, //#bbbbbb
        white: white, //#ffffff

        textColor: '#d0d2d7',
        secondaryTextColor: '#d0d2d7',
        alternateTextColor: '#A6956D',
        canvasColor: '#2D323E',
        pickerHeaderColor: '#a2490e',
        clockCircleColor: '#ed7d31',
        colorAlt: '#6e7a96',
        colorAlt2: '#636e88',
    },
    appBar: {
      color: '#21242d',
      textColor: deepOrange800,
      height: 60,
      padding: '15px',
      titleFontWeight: '800',
    },
    checkbox: {
        boxColor: grey200,
        checkedColor: deepOrange900,
    },
    ..... etc etc ...
};
```

This doesn't work for Material-UI-Next, I know that. But I am looking for a similar approach. I have the theme selector working properly but I don't know what material-ui-next v.1 uses to define the primary1Color, or canvasColor, or each component and what can I actually change from each component, etc.

Just to help you understand how the system works, I have a theme selector component that depending on which one is selected this, or another file loads. In this case, this is a darkOrange theme. Then the MuiUI uses this file to color the components throughout the app without too much CSS and more globally.

Anyone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Theme Customization](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/) covers most of what you're looking for.  Things like [Customizing the palette](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/#palette) are pretty straightforward:

> The theme exposes the following color intentions:
>
> - primary - used to represent primary interface elements for a user.
> - secondary - used to represent secondary interface elements for a user.
> - error - used to represent interface elements that the user should be made aware of.

So `primary`, `secondary`, and `error`, can be expressed as a `PaletteIntention`, which is an interface you can use to define each color:

```js
interface PaletteIntention {
  light?: string;
  main: string;
  dark?: string;
  contrastText?: string;
};
```

Here is an example of applying custom colors to the theme's palette:

```js
import { createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      // light: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
      main: '#ff4400',
      // dark: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
      // contrastText: will be calculated to contast with palette.primary.main
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#0066ff',
      main: '#0044ff',
      // dark: will be calculated from palette.secondary.main,
      contrastText: '#ffcc00',
    },
    // error: will us the default color
  },
});
```

In this example, portions of the `primary` and `secondary` colors are overridden and `error` is left to its default.

To [customize Components](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/#customizing-all-instances-of-a-component-type), you would override specific classes.  Basically, if a class is exposed in a component's CSS API, it can be overridden in the theme.  However, the CSS API documentation is lacking.  On each component page, you'll see a listing of available classes, but there is nothing to explain their role and the attributes they affect.

There is an [open enhancement request](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10389) to add this information to the docs.